# Labels in View are never set

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

So I am programmatically appending a view and setting the labels in said view, but it doesn't appear that those labels are being set. By that I mean the default values in the xib are showing up, rather than the actual values that I am setting.

This is how I append the view-

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if([self.resultsTuples count] != 0){
    NSDictionary* rowData = self.resultsTuples[indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell* tableCell = [self.resultTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
    UIView* cardView = [cardChooser getCardView:rowData];
    [tableCell addSubview:cardView];
    return tableCell;
} else {
    return nil;

}
```

This is how I create the view - a function returns the view -

```
-(UIView*)getProductResultView:(NSDictionary*)component{

ProductResultViewController* productVC = [[ProductResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductResultView" bundle: nil];
NSArray* priceArray = somePriceArray;
NSString* price = [somePriceArray objectAtIndex:0];

[productVC setPrice: price];
[productVC setDescription: someDescription];
[productVC setTitle:someTitle];

return productVC.view;
```

}

And this is what the view controller looks like -

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title{
    _productTitle = title;
    self.titleLabel.text = title;
}

-(void)setPrice:(NSString*)price{
    _price = price;
    NSLog(@"_ PRICE : %@", _price);
    self.priceLabel.text = price;
NSLog(@"PRICE LABEL : %@", self.priceLabel.text);
}

-(void)setDescription:(NSString *)description{
    _description = description;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = description;

}

-(void)setType:(NSString *)type{
    _type = type;
    self.typeLabel.text = type;

}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.typeLabel.text = _type;
    self.priceLabel.text = _price;
    self.titleLabel.text = _productTitle;
    self.descriptionLabel.text = _description;
}
```

After setting the label, the log for price label prints out null, despite the price actually being set(and not being null). Further, viewWilAppear is not called(in other views that I have done I have got around this problem by setting stuff in viewWillAppear).

So why am I getting this problem and how do I get around it?

Comment: Where do you call `getProductResultView` from? Can you try printing out the label itself? E.g. `NSLog(@"%@", self.priceLabel);`

Comment: You should have [super viewWillAppear:animated] in viewWillAppear.